# How long can I expect to wait before a DNS name is transferred to a new server?

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I need to know how long it should take to transfer my domain name from one server to another.

I have a domain name and I am trying to transfer it but one of the local companies said that I can't transfer in less than 2 months with them.

Comment: This isn't really a SO question. You should be able to transfer your domain at any time that you wish, although I'm bordering on giving legal advice now too.

Comment: That policy has nothing to do with your domain name. It's obviously something that your particular web hosting company requires. I assume you agreed to maintain your current hosting plan for at least 2 months in some contract that you agreed to. You'll have to take that up with them.

Comment: those guys refuse to give me  also the user admin and password , it's a programming company and they are reselling the service and all what i need to know is it real that i can't transfer my domain name to another server ?? because i just register with them the new domain name!! and i fell like they are cheating me !!!

Comment: please give me a suggestion what to do??!!

Comment: My suggestion is the only option that you have: talk to your web hosting company. Yes, they *can* transfer your account if they wanted to. They obviously don't want to. Like I said before, you either agreed to commit yourself to their services for a minimum period of time that has not yet elapsed (but will in 2 months), OR they *are* trying to cheat you. Either way, we can't do anything about it. You'll have to take it up with your hosting company.

Comment: Tell them that they can't hold your domain name legally, and ask them to transfer it.

Comment: ok , i think this will solve the problem>

thanks every one for your help

Comment: @TheBigO: Certainly they *could* if you agreed to an arbitrary term of service contract. There isn't enough information here to make that claim. As your very first comment observed, this isn't a question of technical possibilities, it's a legal one. Threatening them with what they can and can't do when they have you under contract is not likely to get you very far.

Comment: i did not sign on any thing yet but i am a fried that they will charge me lots of money to get my domain name!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical perspective: Usually about 10 minutes plus whatever the TTL for the DNS is set to.

You might have contractual obligations that extend that though.